# "with print" -is this correct?

Tags: vocabulary

I would like some help with my english. I wish to write in correct english the following:

Say I am building a machine that delivers something, and it delivers it in sealed packages. Sometimes the packages have something printed on it. And sometimes it does not.

How can I name these packages? or the process? 
For the one without printing I would say "printless package" but I don't know for the other case. And I am even thinking that that does not sound correct.

Comment: Do you have more information about what is being printed? The answers below are good, but another option could be addressed, unaddressed, if the machine were printing address labels.

Comment: Basically what is being printed is content (of the package) and way of use (dosage etc)

Comment: @KansaiRobot that can be called a label. See, for example: https://www.nhs.uk/chq/pages/2607.aspx?categoryid=73&subcategoryid=109

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the printed information is a label of some sort, you can say that the packages with printed information are **labelled** packages, and the others are ***un*labelled** packages.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/label):

> #### label
>
> *noun*
>   3. a: a slip (as of paper or cloth) inscribed and affixed to something for identification or description
>
> > The name is prominently displayed on the label.
>
> b: written or printed matter accompanying an article to furnish
>   identification or other information
>
> > Read the warning label before taking any medicine.

The process can be called *labelling*.

Comment: I would point out that the spelling muru uses, "labelled", is normal in British English. I believe American usage prefers "labeled".

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be **marked** and **unmarked** packages.